# Pascal syntax highlight in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting, pascal

I'm writing in C# the next generation of an old app originally written in Delphi. I often have to look in the old code and wondered if there's anyway to install Pascal syntax highlighting in the Visual Studio 2008 editor.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but you might want to look at [Delphi Prism](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene.aspx) which seems to combine a Delphi compiler into Visual Studio. It might be overkill however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Overkill indeed. I have a separate small editor which is Pascal aware but I wondered if there's an easy solution to stay in my favorite (iow the one I know best) editor,

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.cumps.be/visual-studio-2008-and-php-coloring/ - maybe this could be adjusted from PHP for delphi/pascal

Planned project:

http://www.codeplex.com/Delphi4VisualStudio - this (one day) will support syntax highlighting (but it seems to be overkill too)

Answer (score 0):

I know the guy working on [Delphi4VisualStudio](http://www.codeplex.com/Delphi4VisualStudio).  The project doesn't seem to be active any more, but I know he had syntax highlighting working in the editor.  You could always ask him for just that piece.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it in about 1-2 day's work, but I'm busy trying to make ends meet (seriously). Let me know if you want me to do it.

Prior work (showing [almost] only the syntax highlighting):

Edit: Don't mark me down if this isn't allowed - just let me know. I'd seriously do it for free if I had any spare time at all, I just don't right now.

- [UnrealScript](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/images/3/31/Uc_autocomplete.png)
- [INI Files](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/images/0/0c/Uc_configfile.png)
- [ANTLR grammars](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/images/1/14/NFringeAntlr_QuickInfo.png)
- [StringTemplate templating language](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/images/7/78/NFringeAntlr_StringTemplate1.png)
- [Chapel](http://www.pixelminegames.com/downloads/images/BasicChapelHighlighting.png)

Comment: Thanks for your offer but I no longer need it. No need to lose your time for only for me ;-)